# Yii: Show more than 10 rows in TbGridView

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I want to show rows in descending order in Manage page, so what should I do for displaying more than 10 rows in *.widgets.TbGridView? Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying 30 rows in pagination

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'pagination' => array(
        'pageSize' => 30,
    ),
    'criteria' => $criteria,
));
```

Display Initial rows in descending order

```
$criteria->order = "t.id DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass `CActiveDataProvider` to `CGridView` or `TbGridView` in the manage action. All you need to do is passing the page size to dataprovider:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ),

        'criteria' => $criteria,
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you @hamed, it works for me. I am gonna like you comment after my reputation is >=15.

Comment: @shivakrstha You are welcome. No problem, glad to help you friend :)

Comment: Ok @hamed, we have to share our knowledge to help each other, so I'll accept as well as give answer to public.

Comment: is there any idea of keeping order = "t.id DESC"?